# Combination of bid ask of two instruments

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, market-making, spread, betting

You have 2 instruments: X in which you are quoting 35 @ 40 and product Y in which you are quoting 15 @ 30. We want to make a market on the product X+Y. What is the bid-ask spread you will quote?

Got this in an interview for a quant firm.

Comment: Isn't it 35+15 @ 40+30 i.e. 50 @ 70 ? Analogy: I sell an apple for 40 and an orange for 30. How much should I charge for an apple *and*  an orange.

Comment: To be honest, I’m not too sure but that was my answer as well. Wanted to see if anyone else had a different perspective.